# Purging 7 day old data from SQL while also converting date format to INT

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, getdate

I need to set up an automated data purging (delete 7 day old data) on my SQL box.
The date column which helps me decide on whether to/not to delete the row set is in YYYYMMDD format.

I understand that in order to use GETDATE() I need to convert it (to YYYYMMDD) and here is the conversion i found-

```
CONVERT(CHAR(8), GETDATE(), 112)
```

Below is my delete statement, how do I include the before-mentioned conversion into it to make it work?

```
DELETE FROM dbo.MyDBName
WHERE StreamDateId < DATEADD (DAY, -7, GETDATE())
```

Comment: `CONVERT(CHAR(8), DATEADD (DAY, -7, GETDATE()), 112)`

Comment: Is your column is of type datetime or varchar? if datetime, your query work as it is

Comment: My column (StreamDateId) is of type INT. It gets appended as a result of the tool I use to download Big data into my SQL Server, so changing it to Datetime or Datetime2 will upset the process.

Comment: @Srayan Guhathakurta, If it is int, the value will be in unix time , why is it then your question says it is yyyymmdd format

Comment: When I use the tool called SQLizer to download structured streams from Cosmos into SQL Server, the tool itself appends a timestamp like value to every rowwset (which SQL assigns as type INT) and this looks like a YYYYMMDD format. So I am not generating this field, it is being generated by the tool in YYYYMMDD format and somehow SQL Server is assigning it as an INT. Understanding why and how the tool assigns the timestamp in that manner is however beyond my scope.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best solution for this problem would be to use proper datatype for this date column. Anyway you can do the following....

```
DELETE FROM dbo.MyDBName
WHERE CAST(StreamDateId AS DATETIME) < DATEADD(DAY, -7, GETDATE())
```

OR

```
DELETE FROM dbo.MyDBName
WHERE StreamDateId  < CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), DATEADD(DAY, -7, GETDATE()), 112)
```

Comment: We would expect a sargable query from a 22k user

Comment: The second one is incorrect, we can't do varchar comparison for dates, this will do lexicographoc compare and there will be data loss

Comment: NO it isn't , Convert function on the other side will also return a string value.